# Is it generally safe to install the `linux-firmware` and `*-microcode` packages on older Ubuntu versions?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, firmware, microcode

I'm an Ubuntu LTS user. In the past, I needed to manually install the `linux-firmware` package of a newer Ubuntu version, Cosmic, on my system, Xenial, for it to work correctly.

Now, I wonder: are the hardware-related packages `linux-firmware` and `*-microcode` safe to install in general, on older Ubuntu versions (currently, from `disco` into `bionic`)? How (much) do they interact with the rest of the Ubuntu system?

Comment: Backporting is the process of extracting the changes, and applying them to an older version so as to get the 'feature' (usually increased security) at the minimal cost of time (instead of using all the code & getting it to work).  As a result, I'd expect how safe it is, relates to how well you understand the code, it's ABI/API's & thus can extract & apply it to the older packages.  How skilled are you at that low level of coding?

Comment: ok, edited the question - the term "backport" was incorrect :-)